# How to properly send HTTP response with Python using socket library only?

Tags: python, http, sockets, webserver

I have a very simple web sever written in Python. It listens on port 13000, how can I make it deliver a simple "Hello World" webpage if `http://localhost:13000` is opened in browser?

Right there is my code:

```
# set up socket and connection
while True:
    sock, addr = servSock.accept()
    # WHAT GOES HERE?
    sock.close()
```

As you can see, I am not exactly sure how to actually send back the webpage?

I only have to use the `socket` library.

**EDIT:** The problem is not that I don't know how to formulate the HTTP response, I don't know how to actually make it display in my browser! It just keeps spinning/loading.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Updated according to question change**

Possibly, it keeps spinning because in combination of absence of `Content-Length` and `Connection` headers, browser may assume it's `Connection: keep-alive`, so it continues to receive data from your server forever. Try to send `Connection: close`, and pass actual `Content-Length` to see if that helps.

---

Won't this do what you expect it to? :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8

import socket

MAX_PACKET = 32768

def recv_all(sock):
    r'''Receive everything from `sock`, until timeout occurs, meaning sender
    is exhausted, return result as string.'''
    
    # dirty hack to simplify this stuff - you should really use zero timeout,
    # deal with async socket and implement finite automata to handle incoming data

    prev_timeout = sock.gettimeout()
    try:
        sock.settimeout(0.01)
    
        rdata = []
        while True:
            try:
                rdata.append(sock.recv(MAX_PACKET))
            except socket.timeout:
                return ''.join(rdata)
        
        # unreachable
    finally:
        sock.settimeout(prev_timeout)
    
def normalize_line_endings(s):
    r'''Convert string containing various line endings like \n, \r or \r\n,
    to uniform \n.'''
    
    return ''.join((line + '\n') for line in s.splitlines())

def run():
    r'''Main loop'''
    
    # Create TCP socket listening on 10000 port for all connections, 
    # with connection queue of length 1
    server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, \
                                socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
    server_sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 13000))
    server_sock.listen(1)

    while True:
        # accept connection
        client_sock, client_addr = server_sock.accept()
        
        # headers and body are divided with \n\n (or \r\n\r\n - that's why we
        # normalize endings). In real application usage, you should handle 
        # all variations of line endings not to screw request body
        request = normalize_line_endings(recv_all(client_sock)) # hack again
        request_head, request_body = request.split('\n\n', 1)
        
        # first line is request headline, and others are headers
        request_head = request_head.splitlines()
        request_headline = request_head[0]
        # headers have their name up to first ': '. In real world uses, they
        # could duplicate, and dict drops duplicates by default, so
        # be aware of this.
        request_headers = dict(x.split(': ', 1) for x in request_head[1:])
        
        # headline has form of "POST /can/i/haz/requests HTTP/1.0"
        request_method, request_uri, request_proto = request_headline.split(' ', 3)
        
        response_body = [
            '<html><body><h1>Hello, world!</h1>',
            '<p>This page is in location %(request_uri)r, was requested ' % locals(),
            'using %(request_method)r, and with %(request_proto)r.</p>' % locals(),
            '<p>Request body is %(request_body)r</p>' % locals(),
            '<p>Actual set of headers received:</p>',
            '<ul>',
        ]
        
        for request_header_name, request_header_value in request_headers.iteritems():
            response_body.append('<li><b>%r</b> == %r</li>' % (request_header_name, \
                                                    request_header_value))
    
        response_body.append('</ul></body></html>')
    
        response_body_raw = ''.join(response_body)
        
        # Clearly state that connection will be closed after this response,
        # and specify length of response body
        response_headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html; encoding=utf8',
            'Content-Length': len(response_body_raw),
            'Connection': 'close',
        }
    
        response_headers_raw = ''.join('%s: %s\n' % (k, v) for k, v in \
                                                response_headers.iteritems())
                
        # Reply as HTTP/1.1 server, saying "HTTP OK" (code 200).
        response_proto = 'HTTP/1.1'
        response_status = '200'
        response_status_text = 'OK' # this can be random
        
        # sending all this stuff
        client_sock.send('%s %s %s' % (response_proto, response_status, \
                                                        response_status_text))
        client_sock.send(response_headers_raw)
        client_sock.send('\n') # to separate headers from body
        client_sock.send(response_body_raw)
        
        # and closing connection, as we stated before
        client_sock.close()

run()
```

For more detailed description, please see [description of HTTP protocol](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).

Comment: Yes but...the browser just keeps "spinning" and nothing displays?

Comment: I've updated code sample to work 100% guaranteed :) I hope you will find basic principles of header handling useful, but I recommend you not to rely upon this kind of code and implement full featured HTTP request parser.

Comment: well, you've made a pretty complete answer... though I think the reason it was still spinning (until timeout) is that it was waiting for a double "\n". But at least, your code example is a good snippet to have under the hook, just in case ;)

Comment: Thanks. I think a `\n` has been omitted before `response_headers_raw`.

Comment: I know this is pretty late but I've copied your code and it doesn't work for me. I think it might be the request that is the problem. So is fetch("http://IP:PORT"). The IP is the public ip of the server?

Comment: @EyePatch sorry, I don't understand your question. My code sample has no mention of anything like `fetch`, neither does any answer. Can you clarify?

Comment: sorry it is just that i was talking about how to perform the http request to this server. But i didnt know about port forwarding and i solved it so nevermind

Answer (score 11):

```
# set up socket and connection
while True:
    sock, addr = servSock.accept()
    sock.send("""HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body>Hello World</body></html>
""");
    sock.close()
```

Answer (score 6):

Send back something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 11 Apr 2012 21:29:04 GMT
Server: Python/6.6.6 (custom)
Content-Type: text/html
```

Then the actual html code. Make sure there is a newline after the Content-Type line and before the html.

Answer (score 3):

or, if you just don't want to remember the full protocol, you can find it again using :

```
 % nc stackoverflow.com 80
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Wed, 11 Apr 2012 21:33:49 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 11 Apr 2012 21:32:49 GMT
Vary: *
Date: Wed, 11 Apr 2012 21:32:49 GMT
Content-Length: 206008

[...]
 %
```

well, you shall usually prefer a site that is less verbose (usually serving only a static file) than stackoverflow ;)

The minimal requirements (you'll find on the answer) is :

```
sock.send(r'''HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello, world!

''')
```

two returns are mandatory for the server to get the answer, otherwise the browser waits indefinitely for headers

But to mimic the behaviour of a webserver, don't forget to send your answer *only* after the browser sends you some data followed by two carriage returns, usually you can get what it sends using :

```
 % nc -kl localhost 13000
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:13000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0...
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive

 %
```

so you can improve your test routines

Answer (score 3):

I took a previous answer and edited the code for Python3 utf-8 and bytes encoding. Thanks for the original answer it helped out a lot.

```
import socket

MAX_PACKET = 32768

def recv_all(sock):
    r'''Receive everything from `sock`, until timeout occurs, meaning sender
    is exhausted, return result as string.'''

    # dirty hack to simplify this stuff - you should really use zero timeout,
    # deal with async socket and implement finite automata to handle incoming data

    prev_timeout = sock.gettimeout()
    try:
        sock.settimeout(0.1)

        rdata = []
        while True:
            try:
                # Gotta watch for the bytes and utf-8 encoding in Py3
                rdata.append(sock.recv(MAX_PACKET).decode('utf-8')) 
            except socket.timeout:
                return ''.join(rdata)

        # unreachable
    finally:
        sock.settimeout(prev_timeout)

def normalize_line_endings(s):
    r'''Convert string containing various line endings like \n, \r or \r\n,
    to uniform \n.'''
    test = s.splitlines()
    return ''.join((line + '\n') for line in s.splitlines())

def run():
    r'''Main loop'''

    # Create TCP socket listening on 10000 port for all connections,
    # with connection queue of length 1
    server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                                socket.SOCK_STREAM,
                                socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
    #Added the port 13001 for debuging purposes 

    try:
        server_sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 13000))
        print('PORT 13000')
    except:
        server_sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 13001))
        print('PORT 13001')
    # except:
    #     server_sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 13002))
    #     print('PORT 13002')

    server_sock.listen(1)

    while True:
        # accept connection
        try:
            client_sock, client_addr = server_sock.accept()

            # headers and body are divided with \n\n (or \r\n\r\n - that's why we
            # normalize endings). In real application usage, you should handle
            # all variations of line endings not to screw request body
            request = normalize_line_endings(recv_all(client_sock)) # hack again

            request_head, request_body = request.split('\n\n', 1)

            # first line is request headline, and others are headers
            request_head = request_head.splitlines()
            request_headline = request_head[0]
            # headers have their name up to first ': '. In real world uses, they
            # could duplicate, and dict drops duplicates by default, so
            # be aware of this.
            request_headers = dict(x.split(': ', 1) for x in request_head[1:])

            # headline has form of "POST /can/i/haz/requests HTTP/1.0"
            request_method, request_uri, request_proto = request_headline.split(' ', 3)

            response_body = [
                '<html><body><h1 style="color:red">Hello, world!</h1>',
                '<p>This page is in location %(request_uri)r, was requested ' % locals(),
                'using %(request_method)r, and with %(request_proto)r.</p>' % locals(),
                '<p>Request body is %(request_body)r</p>' % locals(),
                '<p>Actual set of headers received:</p>',
                '<ul>',
            ]

            for request_header_name, request_header_value in request_headers.items():
                response_body.append('<li><b>%r</b> == %r</li>' % (request_header_name,
                                                                    request_header_value))

            response_body.append('</ul></body></html>')

            response_body_raw = ''.join(response_body)

            # Clearly state that connection will be closed after this response,
            # and specify length of response body
            response_headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html; encoding=utf8',
                'Content-Length': len(response_body_raw),
                'Connection': 'close',
            }

            response_headers_raw = ''.join('%s: %s\n' % (k, v) for k, v in \
                                                    response_headers.items())

            # Reply as HTTP/1.1 server, saying "HTTP OK" (code 200).
            response_proto = 'HTTP/1.1'.encode()
            response_status = '200'.encode()
            response_status_text = 'OK'.encode() # this can be random

            # sending all this stuff
            client_sock.send(b'%s %s %s' % (response_proto, response_status,
                                                            response_status_text))
            client_sock.send(response_headers_raw.encode())
            client_sock.send(b'\n') # to separate headers from body
            client_sock.send(response_body_raw.encode())

            # and closing connection, as we stated before

        finally:
            client_sock.close()

run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to Checkout web objects http://www.webob.org/

It's a simple lightweight project for creating http compatible requests and responses. You can do just about anything with you requests/response objects ... Or just delegate the heavy lifting to WebObjects

Sample

```
>>> from webob import Response
>>> res = Response()
>>> res.status
'200 OK'
>>> res.headerlist
[('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'), ('Content-Length', '0')]
>>> res.body
''
```

Comment: This doesn't show how to use it with sockets.

Answer (score -1):

Update to one of the solutions, because latest version asks to send data in byte format

```
while True:
    sock, addr = servSock.accept()
    sock.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"
         +b"Content-Type: text/html\n"
         +b"\n" # Important!
         +b"<html><body>Hello World</body></html>\n");
    sock.shutdown(soket.SHUT_WR)
    sock.close()
```

I could have edited above post, but the queue is full :(.
Also one can use `encode()` method to convert to byte fromat.

Comment: HTTP requires carriage return and a new line character, not just a new line.