# building a local web server and respond data to javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, websocket, webserver, web-deployment

I am trying to learn to build a web application, and that application needs data generated from a python script. After googling around. I found this [link](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-run-a-Python-script-onclick-event-from-JavaScript) and it seems that I need to:

1. write a server side application in Python. Define a URL(route) that runs your script.
2. in my Javascript code, make an HTTP request to the URL defined in Step 1.

In my java script, I have the following ajax call, I'm not too sure what goes in the url field:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "http://localhost:5000",
  cache: false,
  async: "asynchronous",
  dataType: "text",
  success: function (data) {
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log("---->" + data);
  },
  error: function (request, status, error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
  },
});
```

As for my web server side, I wanted to write it from sockets since I want to learn some socket programing as well, so following another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10114266/5186878) I wrote my server below, in this server, my goal is to just return a simple string to prove that this works, but ultimately I want to be able to return a json object :

```
import socket
import threading
import json
import pdb

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.bind(('localhost', 5000))

sock.listen(1)

print("Listening at------>>> ", sock.getsockname())
connections = []

# Reply as HTTP/1.1 server, saying "HTTP OK" (code 200).
response_proto = 'HTTP/1.1'
response_status = '200'
response_status_text = 'OK'  # this can be random
res_status = "{} {} {}".format(response_proto, response_status,
                               response_status_text)

response_body_raw = "hello world"
# Clearly state that connection will be closed after this response,
# and specify length of response body
response_headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'text; encoding=utf8',
    'Content-Length': len(response_body_raw),
    'Connection': 'close',
}

response_headers_raw = ''.join('%s: %s\n' % (k, v) for k, v in
                               response_headers.items())


def handler(c, a):
    global connections
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024)
        print(data)
        for connection in connections:
            # sending all this stuff
            connection.sendall(res_status.encode('utf-8'))
            connection.sendall('\n'.encode('utf-8'))
            connection.sendall(response_headers_raw.encode('utf-8'))
            # to separate headers from body
            connection.sendall('\n'.encode('utf-8'))
            connection.sendall(response_body_raw.encode('utf-8'))

        if not data:
            connections.remove(c)
            c.close()
            break


while True:
    c, a = sock.accept()
    print("Connected by------->>>", a)
    cThread = threading.Thread(target=handler, args=(c, a))
    cThread.daemon = True
    cThread.start()
    connections.append(c)
```

when I run my website using VS code live server extension, I get the following errors:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/?_=1586356660223' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>
> GET http://localhost:5000/?_=1586356660223 net::ERR_FAILED

I looked into the No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error, and it seems that I cannot provide url as *localhost* in my ajax call. if not, then what should I put in the url field if I want to talk to my local server?

Comment: I don't know if there is any better way, but I had a similar issue lately and I just made a web server with Flask.

Comment: @Noah thanks for the answer, so did you run flask locally? if so, what did you put as your url field in the ajax call on your javascript end?

Comment: I'm writing a complete Answer with the configuration of a basic Flask server, similar to the one I used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to your response header:

```
response_headers = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, as already mentioned in my Comment, I used a Flask server to process the POST-Data sent with Ajax.

Basically, you can set up the server like this:

```
from flask import Flask, requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def main_page():
    return "200"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='192.169.178.62')
```

with the `host='192.169.178.62'`, you can specify the IP you want to run your Flask app.
I would suggest you find out your Computers IP, and either use that one to run Flask or use an IP in the same network.

In your AJAX, you need to enter this URL to send the request to.

If anything is not working as it should, feel free to contact me.

Comment: Hey, @ariel's solution worked for me. Thanks for your answer too!