# how to send the response code 301 with socket in python?

Tags: python-3.x

HELP ME. how to send response code 301 with python, i tried to send with response
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://localhost/404.html
Content-Length: %d

but the server doesn't send URL to the web client

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114224/how-to-properly-send-http-response-with-python-using-socket-library-only

Comment: thank you, and I also want to send an image from the webserver to client, can you help me.